# How to manage autoplay of video when browser blocks it: Backup script?

Tags: javascript, video, browser

On my site I have a variety of videos: (1) HTML5 videos AND (2) Vimeo. Both are set to autoplay and no controls. I need to create an alternative for browsers/devices that block those options.

Is there a script to detect when the video is blocked, and a way to replace it with a linked image or text instead?

I also wonder if I can have an audio icon that allows you to turn on/off the audio?

Comment: What's your motivation for this? Give the user an invitation to play the video.

Comment: Hello Adam Azad, thanks for chiming in. We are using background videos. Also, I have a message from the CEO (video) that she wants to autoplay.